# subdomain tomcat under apache2 is ignored (Ubuntu)

Tags: subdomain, apache-2.4, mod-jk, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

My problem seems quite simple, but I have no clue where the problem comes from
I have apache2, mod_jk, and two apps tomcat, main and test
I would like to use main for the "main domain" (so, if I have the url www.mysite.com, I find this main),
and if I send test.mysite.com, I go on test

To simulate this (I have now only one domain), I changed the path of main to www.mysite.com/Main
and the test to test.mysite.com/Test
Problem is, if I go on test.mysite.com/Test, it doesn'T find it.

I use a provider to take care on subdomain existences, and I assume that they did they job correctly to create the subdomain. However, they sent me an ipv6 adress that I can ping

I work 100% under https, so if the user asks for the http, it redirects everything under https

Questions:
How can I see where the problem comes from (my config or the provider)?
How to solve it!

Thanks a lot for your help

Here is my 000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mysite.com
JkMount /Main* ajp13_worker
Redirect /   https://www.mysite.com/

RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*?(?:www\.)?mysite\.[\w\.]+.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:|www\.)mysite\.[\w\.]+(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com$2
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.mysite.com
JkMount /Test* ajp13_worker
Redirect /   https://test.mysite.com/
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)test\.mysite\.[\w\.]+(.*)$ https://test.mysite.com$2
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer was simple : I defined everything in 000-defaults, instead of default-ssl file.
Now, it works